# How to structure my code

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` that contains two "pages" of `UITableViewController`s. These `UITableViewController`s need to be filled with JSON data from the internet. However, this `UIPageViewController` needs to be reused in many places within my app meaning that the data that the `UITableViewController`s use changes.

My question is: how should I structure my code so that I can easily change the data that the `UITableViewController`s access? Should I pass the data to the initialised `UIPageViewController` so that it can pass it on to the `UITableViewController`s, or is there a better way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Singletons are your friend

Comment: @Jeef Singletons are for instances instantiated only once though. I want to be able to have many instances of this `UIPageViewController` throughout the app.

Comment: Well, before posting an answer--how many pages are you displaying at once? Be aware that `UIPageViewController` lets you display view controllers either in paginated fashion (one at a time, like a paginated `UIScrollView`) or two pages at once (like in `iBooks`, with a page flipping animation).

Comment: @MattQuiros I'm displaying 1 page at once in a paginated fashion. Also each view controller will have separate data - they won't all share the same data between them.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a broad question, and there are potentially many different approaches. Which one is best is arguable and not really inferable from the information available.

If you have `UITableViewController`s that are simply displaying downloaded JSON data, then you might want to have a dedicated class that deals simply with downloading the data. E.g. `MyJSONDownloader`.

This class might have a method like `- (NSArray *)getLatestData` that returns the latest things you want to display in a table.

Then in your `UITableViewController` subclasses you want to call this method and display the data accordingly.

I'm assuming from your statement:

> These UITableViewControllers need to be filled with JSON data from the internet. However, this UIPageViewController needs to be reused in many places within my app meaning that the data that the UITableViewControllers use changes.

that you will be downloading data frequently from the web and that this data is constantly changing. (If not then change your question.)